# How does changing dpi in build.props on Android phones work? isn't DPI hardware related?

Tags: android

Also when I change the DPI to a lower value, everything becomes smaller. Aren't they supposed to get bigger?

Comment: As far as i know display density is a configuration value set by the manufacturer. Translating DPI to pixels _does_ rely on hardware details as well as the density value.

Comment: DPI is hardware related, but the number is used to calculate a lot of values when drawing, and to determine which set of resources to use.  So changing that number can have ripple effects.

Comment: Isn't DPI sqrt(w x w + h x h) / diagonal screen length ? Where w and h are pixels in width and height of display.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the answer. I'm posting it here for someone else with the same doubt.

The purpose of the DPI setting is to make sure things aren't too large or too small depending on your screen size vs resolution. A larger device, like a tablet with the same screen resolution as your phone would have a lower DPI screen since it's bigger. If your phones screen was the size of a tablet all the stuff on it would look huge if you kept the same dpi. A lower DPI makes things smaller and allows this tablet to show more stuff on the screen at once.